# What does =_= mean in JavaScript or HTML?

Tags: javascript, xss

Reading this [XSS cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html), I noticed a special usage I have never seen:

```
<img src="/" =_=" title="onerror='prompt(1)'">
```

What does "=_=" mean? It's below the sentence "On Mouse Over​".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an attribute on the element. It doesn't have any meaning by itself, so it may be present simply as a red herring.

Prettified, the code is:

```
<img
  src="/"
  =_=" title="
  onerror='prompt(1)'"
>
```

In HTML, `=` in an attribute specifies the delimiter between the attribute name and the attribute value, so it's:

```
=_=" title="
^^ attribute name

=_=" title="
  ^ delimiter between attribute name and attribute value

=_=" title="
   ^ attribute value contents delimiter

=_=" title="
    ^^^^^^^ attribute value

=_=" title="
           ^ attribute value contents delimiter
```

And you could retrieve the attribute value if you wanted.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
console.log(img.getAttribute('=_'));
```

```html
<img
  src="/"
  =_=" title="
  onerror='prompt(1)'"
>
```

Note that the attribute name is `=_`, not `=_=` - the final `=` is the delimiter, not part of the attribute name.

The "XSS" is caused only by the `src` and the `onerror`, not by anything else. Wherever you're encountering this, the `=_` probably doesn't do anything at all. It *could*, but it probably doesn't.

```html
<img src="/" onerror='prompt(1)'">
```

Comment: It targets some WAF parsers so they think the `onerror` part is inside the `title` attribute and thus "harmless".